# ul/li tags showing too much space in versions of Outlook Office 365

Tags: html, email, outlook, office365, padding

[image]

I have an email for a client I'm working on right now. In my code that I've attached Outlook 365 seems to be stripping out the padding I have set in the ul tag. It's only showing up wonky for that version of outlook specifically. All other versions the bullets look fine and are aligned correctly. Would someone be able to take a look at my code and see if they can offer any solutions?

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" style="width:100% !important;">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" style="font-size:0px; line-height:0px; vertical-align: top;">
      <p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:22px; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;  vertical-align: top; color:#0033a0;margin: 35px 0px 0px 15px;">
        INDICATION
      </p>
      <p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:20px; font-weight: normal; text-align: left;  vertical-align: top; color:black;margin: 0px 0px 10px 15px;">
        ZEPOSIA<sup style="font-size:10px;">&reg;</sup> (ozanimod) is a prescription medicine used to treat moderately to<br> severely active ulcerative colitis (UC) in adults.<br>It is not known if ZEPOSIA is safe and effective in children.
      </p>
      <p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size:19px; line-height:22px; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;  vertical-align: top; color:#0033a0;margin: 20px 0px 0px 15px;">
        IMPORTANT SAFETY INFORMATION
      </p>
      <p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:19px; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;  vertical-align: top; color:black;margin: 0px 0px 0px 15px;">
        Do not take ZEPOSIA if you:
      </p>

      <ul style="padding:0px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 32px; line-height:20px;font-size:16px;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">
        <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;"><span style="color:black;">have had a heart attack, chest pain (unstable angina), stroke or mini-stroke (transient ischemic attack or TIA), or certain types of heart failure in the last<br> 6 months</span></li>
        <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;"><span style="color:black;">have or have had a history of certain types of an irregular or abnormal<br> heartbeat (arrhythmia) that is not corrected by a pacemaker</span></li>
        <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;"><span style="color:black;">have untreated, severe breathing problems during your sleep (sleep apnea)</span></li>
        <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;"><span style="color:black;">take certain medicines called monoamine oxidase (MAO) inhibitors (such as selegiline, phenelzine, linezolid)</span>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:20px; font-weight: normal; text-align: left;  vertical-align: top; color:black;margin: 15px 0px 15px 15px;">
        Talk to your healthcare provider before taking ZEPOSIA if you have any of<br> these conditions or do not know if you have any of these conditions.
      </p>
      <p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:20px; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;  vertical-align: top; color:black;margin: 10px 0px 0px 15px;">
        ZEPOSIA may cause serious side effects, including:
      </p>
      <ul style="padding:0px;margin: 0px 0px 0px 32px; line-height:20px;font-size:16px;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">
        <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;">
          <span style="color:black;"><strong>Infections.</strong> ZEPOSIA can increase your risk of serious infections that can be<br> life-threatening and cause death. ZEPOSIA lowers the number of white<br> blood cells (lymphocytes) in your blood. This will usually go back to normal within 3 months of stopping treatment. Your healthcare provider may do a<br> blood test of your white blood cells before you start taking ZEPOSIA.
                                          </span>
        </li>
        <p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:20px; font-weight: normal; vertical-align: top; color:black;margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;">
          Call your healthcare provider right away if you have any of these symptoms<br> of an infection during treatment with ZEPOSIA and for 3 months after your<br> last dose of ZEPOSIA:</p>
        <ul style="padding:0px;margin: 0px 0px 0px 16px; line-height:20px;font-size:16px;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;"><span style="color:black;">fever</span></li>
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;"><span style="color:black;">feeling very tired </span></li>
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;"><span style="color:black;">flu-like symptoms </span></li>
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;"><span style="color:black;">cough</span></li>
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;"><span style="color:black;">painful and frequent urination (signs of a urinary tract infection)</span></li>
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;"><span style="color:black;">rash</span></li>
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;"><span style="color:black;">    headache with fever, neck stiffness, sensitivity to light, nausea, or<br> confusion (these may be symptoms of meningitis, an infection of the<br> lining around your brain and spine)</span></li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
      <p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:20px; font-weight: normal; text-align: left;  vertical-align: top; color:black;margin: 15px 0px 15px 32px;">
        Your healthcare provider may delay starting or may stop your ZEPOSIA treatment if you have an infection.
      </p>
      <ul style="padding:0px;margin: 0px 0px 0px 32px; line-height:20px;font-size:16px;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">
        <li style="margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;color:#ef453d;">
          <span style="color:black;"><strong>Progressive multifocal leukoencephalopathy (PML).</strong> ZEPOSIA can<br> increase your risk for PML, which is a rare brain infection that usually leads<br> to death or severe disability. If PML happens, it usually happens in people<br> with weakened immune systems but has happened in people who do not<br> have weakened immune systems. Symptoms of PML get worse over days to weeks. Call your doctor right away if you have any new or worsening<br> symptoms of PML that have lasted several days, including: weakness on<br> one (1) side of your body, changes in your vision, changes in your thinking<br> or memory, confusion, changes in your personality, loss of coordination in<br> your arms or legs, decreased strength, and/or problems with balance.
                                          </span>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul style="padding:0px;margin: 0px 0px 0px 32px; line-height:20px;font-size:16px;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">
        <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;">
          <span style="color:black;"><strong>Slow heart rate (also known as bradyarrhythmia) when you start taking ZEPOSIA.</strong> ZEPOSIA may cause your heart rate to temporarily slow down, especially during the first 8 days. You will have a test to check the electrical activity of your heart called an electrocardiogram (ECG) before you take<br> your first dose of ZEPOSIA.
                                          </span>
        </li>
        <p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:20px; font-weight: normal; vertical-align: top; color:black;margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;">
          Call your healthcare provider if you experience the following symptoms of<br> slow heart rate:</p>

        <ul style=" padding:0px;margin: 0px 0px 0px 16px; line-height:20px;font-size:16px;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;"><span style="color:black;">dizziness</span></li>
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;"><span style="color:black;">lightheadedness</span></li>
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;"><span style="color:black;">feeling like your heart is beating slowly or skipping beats </span></li>
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;"><span style="color:black;">shortness of breath</span></li>
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;"><span style="color:black;">confusion</span></li>
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;"><span style="color:black;">chest pain</span></li>
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;"><span style="color:black;">    tiredness</span></li>
        </ul>
      </ul>

      <p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:20px; font-weight: normal; text-align: left;  vertical-align: top; color:black;margin: 15px 0px 0px 15px;">
        Follow directions from your healthcare provider when starting ZEPOSIA and<br> when you miss a dose.
      </p>
      <p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:20px; font-weight: normal; text-align: left;  vertical-align: top; color:black;margin: 15px 0px 0px 15px;">
        Continue reading for additional possible serious side effects of ZEPOSIA.
      </p>
      <p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:20px; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;  vertical-align: top; color:black;margin: 15px 0px 0px 15px;">
        Before taking ZEPOSIA, tell your healthcare provider about all of your<br> medical conditions, including if you:
      </p>
      <ul style="padding:0px;margin: 0px 0px 0px 32px; line-height:20px;font-size:16px;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">
        <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;">
          <span style="color:black;">have a fever or infection, or are unable to fight infections due to a disease,<br> or take or have taken medicines that lower your immune system
                                          </span>
        </li>
        <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;">
          <span style="color:black;">received a vaccine in the past 30 days or are scheduled to receive a<br> vaccine. ZEPOSIA may cause vaccines to be less effective
                                          </span>
        </li>
        <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;">
          <span style="color:black;">before you start ZEPOSIA, your healthcare provider may give you a<br> chickenpox (Varicella Zoster Virus) vaccine if you have not had one before
                                          </span>
        </li>
        <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;">
          <span style="color:black;">have had chickenpox or have received the vaccine for chickenpox. Your healthcare provider may do a blood test for the chickenpox virus. You may<br> need to get the full course of the vaccine and wait 1 month before taking ZEPOSIA
                                          </span>
        </li>
        <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;">
          <span style="color:black;">have a slow heart rate
                                          </span>
        </li>
        <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;">
          <span style="color:black;">have an irregular or abnormal heartbeat (arrhythmia)
                                          </span>
        </li>
        <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;">
          <span style="color:black;">have a history of stroke
                                          </span>
        </li>
        <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;">
          <span style="color:black;">have or have had heart problems, including a heart attack or chest pain
                                          </span>
        </li>
        <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;">
          <span style="color:black;">have high blood pressure
                                          </span>
        </li>
        <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;">
          <span style="color:black;">have liver problems
                                          </span>
        </li>
        <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;">
          <span style="color:black;">have breathing problems, including during your sleep
                                          </span>
        </li>
        <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;">
          <span style="color:black;">have eye problems, especially an inflammation of the eye called uveitis
                                          </span>
        </li>
        <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;">
          <span style="color:black;">have diabetes
                                          </span>
        </li>
        <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;">
          <span style="color:black;">are or plan to become pregnant or if you become pregnant within 3 months<br> after you stop taking ZEPOSIA. ZEPOSIA may harm your unborn baby. If<br> you are a female who can become pregnant, talk to your healthcare provider about what birth control method is right for you during your treatment with ZEPOSIA and for 3 months after you stop taking ZEPOSIA
                                          </span>
        </li>
        <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;">
          <span style="color:black;">are breastfeeding or plan to breastfeed. It is not known if ZEPOSIA passes<br> into your breast milk. Talk to your healthcare provider about the best way to feed your baby if you take ZEPOSIA
                                          </span>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:20px; font-weight: normal; text-align: left;  vertical-align: top; color:black;margin: 15px 0px 0px 15px;">
        <strong>Tell your healthcare provider about all the medicines you take or have recently taken,</strong> including prescription and over-the-counter medicines,<br> vitamins, and herbal supplements. Using ZEPOSIA with other medicines can cause serious
        side effects. Especially tell your healthcare provider if you take<br> or have taken:
      </p>
      <ul style="padding:0px;margin: 0px 0px 0px 32px; line-height:20px;font-size:16px;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">
        <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;">
          <span style="color:black;">medicines that affect your immune system, such as alemtuzumab
                                          </span>
        </li>
        <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;">
          <span style="color:black;">medicines to control your heart rhythm (antiarrhythmics) or heartbeat
                                          </span>
        </li>
        <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;">
          <span style="color:black;">CYP2C8 inducers such as rifampin
                                          </span>
        </li>
        <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;">
          <span style="color:black;">CYP2C8 inhibitors such as gemfibrozil (medicine to treat high fat in your<br> blood)
                                          </span>
        </li>
        <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;">
          <span style="color:black;">opioids (pain medicine), medicines to treat depression, and medicines to<br> treat Parkinson’s disease
                                          </span>
        </li>
        <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;">
          <span style="color:black;">medicines to control your heart rate and blood pressure (beta blocker<br> medicines and calcium channel blocker medicines) 
                                          </span>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:20px; font-weight: normal; text-align: left;  vertical-align: top; color:black;margin: 15px 0px 15px 15px;">
        You should not receive <strong>live</strong> vaccines during treatment with ZEPOSIA, for at<br> least 1 month before taking ZEPOSIA and for 3 months after you stop taking ZEPOSIA. Vaccines may not work as well when given during treatment with
        ZEPOSIA.
      </p>
      <p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:20px; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;  vertical-align: top; color:black;margin: 10px 0px 0px 15px;">
        ZEPOSIA can cause serious side effects, including:
      </p>
      <ul style="padding:0px;margin: 0px 0px 0px 32px; line-height:20px;font-size:16px;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">
        <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;">
          <span style="color:black;"><strong>liver problems.</strong> Your healthcare provider will do blood tests to check your<br> liver before you start taking ZEPOSIA. Call your healthcare provider right<br> away if you have any of the following symptoms:
                                          </span>
        </li>
        <ul style="padding:0px;margin: 0px 0px 0px 16px; line-height:20px;font-size:16px;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;"><span style="color:black;">unexplained nausea</span></li>
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;"><span style="color:black;">vomiting</span></li>
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;"><span style="color:black;">stomach area (abdominal) pain </span></li>
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;"><span style="color:black;">tiredness</span></li>
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;"><span style="color:black;">loss of appetite</span></li>
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;"><span style="color:black;">yellowing of the whites of your eyes or skin</span></li>
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;"><span style="color:black;">    dark colored urine</span></li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
      <ul style="padding:0px;margin: 0px 0px 0px 32px; line-height:20px;font-size:16px;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">
        <li style="margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;">
          <span style="color:black;">   <strong>increased blood pressure.</strong> Your healthcare provider should check your<br> blood pressure during treatment with ZEPOSIA. A sudden, severe increase<br> in blood pressure (hypertensive crisis) can happen when you eat certain<br> foods that contain high levels of tyramine.</span>
        </li>
        <li style="margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;">
          <span style="color:black;">   <strong>breathing problems.</strong> Some people who take ZEPOSIA have shortness of breath. Call your healthcare provider right away if you have new <br>or worsening breathing problems.</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul style="padding:0px;margin: 0px 0px 0px 32px; line-height:20px;font-size:16px;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">
        <li style="margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;">
          <span style="color:black;"><strong>a problem with your vision called macular edema.</strong> Your risk of macular edema is higher if you have diabetes or have had an inflammation of your<br> eye called uveitis. Your healthcare provider should test your vision before<br> you start taking ZEPOSIA if you are at higher risk for macular edema or any time you notice vision changes during treatment with ZEPOSIA. Call your healthcare provider right away if you have any of the following symptoms:</span>
        </li>

        <ul style="padding:0px;margin: 0px 0px 0px 16px; line-height:20px;font-size:16px;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;"><span style="color:black;">blurriness or shadows in the center of your vision</span></li>
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;"><span style="color:black;">sensitivity to light</span></li>
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;"><span style="color:black;">a blind spot in the center of your vision</span></li>
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;"><span style="color:black;">unusually colored vision</span></li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
      <ul style="padding:0px;margin: 0px 0px 0px 32px; line-height:20px;font-size:16px;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">
        <li style="margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;">
          <span style="color:black;"><strong>swelling and narrowing of the blood vessels in your brain.</strong> Posterior Reversible Encephalopathy Syndrome (PRES) is a rare condition that has happened with ZEPOSIA and with drugs in the same class. Symptoms of <br>PRES usually get better when you stop taking ZEPOSIA. If left untreated, it<br> may lead to stroke. Your healthcare provider will do a test if you have any symptoms of PRES. Call your healthcare provider right away if you have any<br> of the following symptoms:</span>
        </li>
        <ul style="padding:0px;margin: 0px 0px 0px 16px; line-height:20px;font-size:16px;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;"><span style="color:black;">sudden severe headache</span></li>
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;"><span style="color:black;">sudden confusion</span></li>
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;"><span style="color:black;">sudden loss of vision or other changes in your vision</span></li>
          <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;"><span style="color:black;">seizure</span></li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
      <p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:20px; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;  vertical-align: top; color:black;margin: 15px 0px 0px 15px;">
        The most common side effects of ZEPOSIA can include:
      </p>
      <ul style="padding:0px;margin: 0px 0px 0px 34px; line-height:20px;font-size:16px;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">
        <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;">
          <span style="color:black;">upper respiratory tract infections
                                          </span>
        </li>
        <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;">
          <span style="color:black;">elevated liver enzymes
                                          </span>
        </li>
        <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;">
          <span style="color:black;">low blood pressure when you stand up (orthostatic hypotension)
                                          </span>
        </li>
        <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;">
          <span style="color:black;">painful and frequent urination (signs of urinary tract infection)
                                          </span>
        </li>
        <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;">
          <span style="color:black;">back pain
                                          </span>
        </li>
        <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;">
          <span style="color:black;">high blood pressure
                                          </span>
        </li>
        <li style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;color:#ef453d;">
          <span style="color:black;">headache
                                          </span>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:20px; font-weight: normal; text-align: left;  vertical-align: top; color:black;margin: 15px 0px 10px 15px;">
        These are not all of the possible side effects of ZEPOSIA. For more<br> information, ask your healthcare provider or pharmacist.
      </p>
      <p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:20px; font-weight: normal; text-align: left;  vertical-align: top; color:black;margin: 15px 0px 30px 15px;">
        Call your healthcare provider for medical advice about side effects. You may <br>report side effects to FDA at <a href="#" style="color:black;text-decoration: none;">1-800-FDA-1088</a>.
      </p>
      <p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:20px; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;  vertical-align: top; color:black;margin: 10px 0px 60px 15px;">
        Please see full <a href="https://packageinserts.bms.com/pi/pi_zeposia.pdf" style="color:#008dd2;text-decoration:underline;">Prescribing Information</a>, inlcuding <a href="https://packageinserts.bms.com/medguide/medguide_zeposia.pdf" style="color:#008dd2;text-decoration:underline;">Medication Guide</a>.
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```